# What is this number system?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hex

I have a SQL Server database that has two fields

```
First field value:  30303030303030333234
Second field value:  0000000324
```

Now, I'm told the first value is hexadecial, but it doesn't look anything like hexadecimal to me. It isn't too hard to crack--the second number is embedded in the first, with every number in the second being accompanied by a "3". So the second number is 10 digits, and the first number is 20 digits, with 10 "3"s added. I could use a string operation to convert, but I'm wondering if the first number is actually any established number system or if there is a standard way to convert?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about decoding a trivial encoding system.

Comment: @wallyk, not sure that makes it off-topic. Yes, it's easy to those skilled in the art, but that's not everyone here.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it looks *exactly* like hexadecimal, though its values are limited to the small number stored in the second field.

The first field is simply the ASCII (or Unicode) code points for characters in the second field:

```
ASCII code
point (hex)  Character
===========  =========
    30           0
    31           1
    32           2
    33           3
    34           4
    35           5
    36           6
    37           7
    38           8
    39           9
```

Now there *may* be a valid reason why they've chosen to store the data as both a textual and hexadecimal string but I can't think of a good on off the top of my head. In any case, it rather seems violates 3NF (though there are again sometimes valid reasons to do this).

As to how to convert them, there are numerous articles (such as [this one](http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/sql-server-convert-a-string-into-a-hex-string-and-back-sql-sqlserver/)) on the web that you'll find if you look up `sqlserver ascii hex string` in your favourite search engine.

Comment: I have looked at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/2969/ . I'm trying to create a function but I can't use the sp_executesql proc in a function so I'm trying to build a string. Problem is I end up with:

`set @returnstring = @returnstring + char(cast('0x' + @pair  as varbinary))`

...where @pair is each individual pair of hex characters in the string (I'm looping here). That is no good as that is a string and I need to end up with something like:

`select char(CAST(0x34 as varbinary))`  instead of  `select char(CAST('0x34' as varbinary)) . Any idea how to do that?